# Python testing on different dates

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-datetime

I have an application where I would like to test whether or not the server updates the data correctly. The server is set to update the data at every midnight. I want to use Python to test this, however it is inconvenient to have a test running over night for this. I would also like to test edge cases such as months with less days, daylight savings, etc. Is there any way to mock a system time or fast forward in time in python?

Comment: https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Comment: Thank you! That looks exactly what I was looking for.